# Compare Images in Pygame(Not Pixel by Pixel)

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have an array of images in which there are multiple images , say for example,

```
guns = [pygame.image.load('gun1.jpg'),pygame.image.load('gun2.jpg'),pygame.image.load('gun3.jpg'),pygame.image.load('gun4.jpg')]
```

These all images are yellow rectangles and I have changed some of them to white rectangles of same dimensions to make them disappear in my code.

Now I have to check that in that array of `guns` which images are white and which are not.

For that I tried looping:

```
for i in range(0,window_size):
    print('wolla2!')
    if guns[i] is whiteIm:
        print('wolla!')
    i+=1
```

where **whiteIm** is the white colored image I replaced with and **window_size** is the number of images. But I know I can't do that like this.

*How to check that the image is white or not in the array?*

Comment: What precisely makes an image white or yellow?

Comment: These are their default colors. gun1.jpg, gun2.jpg ... they all are yellow images.....I am replacing them with a white Image. whiteIm = **pygame.load.image('white.jpg')** where  __white.jpg__ is the white image.

Comment: ok, thanks - if these images are identified, you could maybe subclass the `Image` class to add an attribute? (in Python, you might even be able to add this attribute dynamically?)  Alternatively, is the images are stored in an array, it might be easier to maintain an array of booleans in parallel, where False is yellow, and True is White for instance.

Comment: Nice Idea. I ll try it.. But isn't it possible to compare them? That would save my lot of time and code. It's just a part of my code... I have to do it everywhere otherwise.

Comment: You are naming these files after "whitening" them... can you add a `w_` prefix, and then segregate based on their name?  `gun1.jpg` --> `w_gun1.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are Four plus One possibilities for you to evaluate, and choose from, based on your circumstances:

#### Subclass Image:

you could maybe subclass the Image class to add an attribute?

#### Dynamically add an attribute to Image:

in Python, you can add an attribute dynamically: `gun1.color = "w"`

#### Maintain a parallel array:

the images are stored in an array, it might be easy to maintain an array of booleans in parallel, where False is yellow, and True is White for instance.

#### prefix the name of the image file:

As you are naming these files after "whitening" them, you could add a `w_` prefix, and then segregate based on their name? `gun1.jpg` --> `w_gun1.jpg`
These images could then be segregated based on the first characters of their `__name__`

#### Add a tag: (maybe?)

in tkinter, you can add tags to canvas objects, and manipulate them as a group based on their tags... maybe pygame offers a similar possibility?

Comment: Not tkinter... But that making an array of booleans in parallel approach worked just fine for me. Thanks :)